# Silly question about Directional Derivatives.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm struggling with a quite silly point about $\mathbb{R}^n$ directional derivative and the general notion of the same construct about Manifold theory.
I mean:

By definition we have the directional derivative:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(p+t\vec{v}) - f(p)}{t}............(1)$$

And in manifold theory we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(f) = \displaystyle \sum^n_{i = 0} \frac{\partial f}{\partial {x^i}} \frac{dx^i}{dt}..................(2)$$

My point is: under the perspective of $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{v}}$$ we have no "extra term" such as  $\frac{dx^i}{dt}$.
Nevertheless, both (1) and (2) are directional derivatives. And then is common to read that "partial derivatives are the basis of $T_p (M)$" or "partial derivatives are directional derivatives".

**My question is:** how can we relate precisely the notion of (1) with (2) and then with Tangent space and basis of tangent space?

Comment: The velocity of a curve on a manifold is a function that eats a function on the manifold and gives back the directional derivative of the function along the curve. One of the best explanations is given here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pepU_7NJSGM&index=5&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_

Comment: You should look John Lee's book **Introduction to Smooth Manifold** Chapter 3. It will gives you understanding how tangent space defined, by the motivation from directional derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^n$.